# In F#, why can't the "when" in a type constraint line up with the apostrophe in the generic type?

Tags: f#

I've noticed that I get a compiler error on the following:

```ml
type A<'T
      when 'T : comparison>() = // this is fine
    class end

type B<'T
        when 'T : comparison>() = // this is fine
    class end

type C<'T
       when 'T : comparison>() = // error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in type name. Expected '>' or other token
    class end
```

In `A` the `when` starts under the `<`, in `B` the `when` starts under the `T` and in `C` the `when` starts under the `'`. It seems kinda weird to me that it fails to compile on a specific indentation, when starting one character left or right of it is fine. How come this is the case?

Comment: I'm struggling to find the difference between these examples. Please make sure that indentations are correct

Comment: @BohdanStupak his code is correct, checked on my IDE.

Comment: In retrospect, I believe this may be an actual F# bug, I've reported it here in case https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/6938